# Java Errors and Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I am currently studying java Exception handling and I'm confused with Exceptions and Errors.
I want to know to which category of Throwable class (Exception or Error/[Throwable class](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/Exception-in-java1.png)) does following errors goes

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println(x);
        }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
x cannot be resolved to a variable
```

My problem is it shows "Exception in thread main" and at the same time " java.lang.Error:" so to which category Exception or Error does these type of mistakes goes.

I think it goes under Error class

And also I got to know in a video that Exceptions are caused by our program errors and they are recoverable.And Errors are not caused by our program.Then that means errors like above does not goes under Error class.This is not clear for me please some one help me to clarify this.

Comment: Can not really reproduce that error message. You should get something similar to this: [DEMO](https://ideone.com/LVCZfL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors and Exceptions are run time errors, problems that occur while your program runs. In this case, your program does not run. You can't run it because you can't compile it. This is not a run time error, it's a compile time error, and compile time errors are not represented as Java throwable classes.

It looks like you are using a development environment that is written in Java itself, and the way it reports compile time errors in your code has this confusing bit `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error`. That bit exposes a detail about how the development environment is implemented, it's not a part of your program.